# How to flatten a hierarchy in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Imagine this table:

| Level | Name | Parent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| LevelA | Fruit |  |
| LevelB | Apple | Fruit |
| LevelA | Moving |  |
| LevelB | FourWheelers | Moving |
| LevelC | Car | FourWheelers |
| LevelC | Truck | FourWheelers |

what I try to achieve is a hierarchy which looks like that:

> Fruit
>
> > Apple

> Moving
>
> > FourWheelers
> >
> > > Car

> > > Truck

Whatever I tried so far, it didn't work out. Especially I need the level as independed attribute so that I can e.g. create a widget for level B only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the pattern here to flatten a hierarchy.

https://www.daxpatterns.com/parent-child-hierarchies/

[image]

Create 4 calculated columns as follows:

```
EntityPath = 
PATH ('Table'[Name], 'Table'[Parent] )


Level1 = 
VAR LevelNumber = 1
VAR LevelKey = PATHITEM ( 'Table'[EntityPath], LevelNumber )
RETURN
    LevelKey


Level2 = 
VAR LevelNumber = 2
VAR LevelKey = PATHITEM ( 'Table'[EntityPath], LevelNumber )
RETURN
    LevelKey


Level3 = 
VAR LevelNumber = 3
VAR LevelKey = PATHITEM ( 'Table'[EntityPath], LevelNumber )
RETURN
    LevelKey
```

[image]

Use the new columns in your hierarchy.